# Boost string algorithm error

Tags: c++, boost

I have a problem with boost string algorithm library.
I tried split and tokenize to split/tokenize wstring, but I always get this following error

**The code**

```
std::vector<std::wstring> tokenize(const std::wstring& input) {
    std::vector<std::wstring> output;
    boost::char_separator<wchar_t> sep(L";");
    boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<wchar_t>> tokens(input, sep);
    std::for_each(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(),
        [&output] (std::wstring ws) {
            output.push_back(ws);
        }
    );
    return output;
}
```

**The error messages**

```
 error C2664: 'std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>::_String_const_iterator
(const std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>> &)' : 
cannot convert argument 1 
from 'std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<wchar_t>>>' 
to 'const std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>> &'
```

I have tried other means, like `boost::split` or changing wstring to string, but it doesn't work.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307883/error-c2664-converting-from-from-const-stdstring-to-stdstring

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source of `tokenizer.hpp`, tokenizer is defined as this:

```
  template <
    typename TokenizerFunc = char_delimiters_separator<char>, 
    typename Iterator = std::string::const_iterator,
    typename Type = std::string
  >
  class tokenizer {
  ...
```

You specified only `TokenizerFunc` for the class template, but forgot to specify `Iterator` and `Type`. As a result, you got that error: `cannot convert argument 1 ...wchar_t... to ...char...`

To make you code running, you should specify all parameters for boost::tokenizer, e.g:

```
typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<wchar_t>, std::wstring::const_iterator, std::wstring > tokenizer;
```

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

std::vector<std::wstring> tokenize(const std::wstring& input) {
  std::vector<std::wstring> output;

  typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<wchar_t>, std::wstring::const_iterator, std::wstring > tokenizer;
  boost::char_separator<wchar_t> sep(L";");
  tokenizer tokens(input, sep);

  std::for_each(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(),
    [&output] (std::wstring ws) {
      output.push_back(ws);
    }
  );

  return output;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  auto v = tokenize(L"one;two;three");
  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::wstring, wchar_t>(std::wcout, L" "));

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
one two three
```

Comment: I agree with the analysis here.